# Is it possible to post binaries to usenet with Python?

Tags: python, nntp

I'm trying to use the nntplib that comes with python to make some posts to usenet. However I can't figure out how to post binary files using the .post method.

I can post plain text files just fine, but not binary files. any ideas?

-- EDIT--

So thanks to Adrian's comment below I've managed to make one step towards my goal.

I now use the email library to make a multipart message and attach the binary files to the message. However I can't seem to figure out how to pass that message directly to the nttplib post method.

I have to first write a temporary file, then read it back in to the nttplib method. There has to be a way to do this all in memory....any suggestions?

Comment: please post new questions in a separate question... (still have a look at the edit to my answer)

Comment: I figured it was still part of the same original question, how to post binaries to usenet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to MIME-encode your post: a binary post in an NNTP newsgroup is like a mail with an attachment.

the file has to be encoded in ASCII, generally using the `base64` encoding, then the encoded file is packaged iton a multipart MIME message and posted...

have a look at the [`email`](http://docs.python.org/library/email.html#module-email) module: it implements all that you want.

i encourage you to read [`RFC3977`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3977) which is the  official standard defining the NNTP protocol.

*for the second part of your question:*

use [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#module-StringIO) to build a fake file object from a string (the `post()` method of nntplib accepts open file objects).
`email.Message` objects have a `as_string()` method to retrieve the content of the message as a plain string.